# Laravel 5: troubles with models relationships

Tags: model, relationship, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a simple Laravel 5 app for testing purposes.
Everything seem to be set-up correctly (database, tables, etc.).
However I'm still getting the following error when trying to query my database through relationships:

PHP ARTISAN TINKER:

```
>>> App\Product::first()->name;
=> "Laptop A"

>>> App\Product::first() -> order -> id;
PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1
>>> App\Product::first() -> order -> status;
PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1
```

Here are my tables (migrations):

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->string('status');
});


Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('orders_id')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('sn');
});
```

Here are my 2 models:

//File: App\Order.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model {

public function products()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

}
```

//File: App\Product.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

public function order()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand why it does not work?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your foreign key doesn't follow the convention (which would be singular, `order_id`) therefore you have to specify it:

```php
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'orders_id');
}
```

(And the same for the inverse relationship)

---

Also note that `first()` will return `null` if no order is associated with the product. In real code, it is recommended to check if the return value of `first()` is `null`